# Measuring network properties at intermediate time steps

Tags: r, python-2.7, graph-theory, networkx

I have to measure certain properties of a Barabasi Albert graph, like degree distribution, at certain steps of the growth of the network (i.e. at N=100, N=1000, N=10000 etc.). I know how to generate such a graph with networkx, but it really is unclear to me how to access these properties during the growth process.

There is no code to show you, I need a hint for the algorithm itself, some examples would be much appreciated. I use Python 2.7, but I am comfortable with R as well if necessary.

Comment: If this is part of an assignment, I suspect that part of the reason the instructor assigned the requirement for intermediate details is to force you to code the algorithm yourself, rather than just using a built-in command.

Answer (score 0):

I think the function the you are looking for is [Barbabasi Albert Graph function](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9.1/reference/generated/networkx.generators.random_graphs.barabasi_albert_graph.html) in [netwrokx](https://networkx.github.io/). On looking into the source code for the above mentioned function [on this link](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9.1/_modules/networkx/generators/random_graphs.html#barabasi_albert_graph) (based on networkx docs), the steps are given in the comments. You can print the properties of the Graph in each iteration of `while source<n:` loop to get the properties you desire.

Answer (score 0):

based on @Mohammed Kashif's answer, here is the modified source code of Barabasi Albert graph which returns a dictionary keyed on number of nodes and with values array of degrees:

```
import random
import networkx as nx

def _random_subset(seq,m):
    """ Return m unique elements from seq.

    This differs from random.sample which can return repeated
    elements if seq holds repeated elements.
    """
    targets=set()
    while len(targets)<m:
        x=random.choice(seq)
        targets.add(x)
    return targets

def barabasi_albert_graph_modified(n, m, seed=None):

    if m < 1 or  m >=n:
        raise nx.NetworkXError(\
              "Barabási-Albert network must have m>=1 and m<n, m=%d,n=%d"%(m,n))
    if seed is not None:
        random.seed(seed)

    # Add m initial nodes (m0 in barabasi-speak)
    G=nx.empty_graph(m)
    G.name="barabasi_albert_graph(%s,%s)"%(n,m)
    # Target nodes for new edges
    targets=list(range(m))
    # List of existing nodes, with nodes repeated once for each adjacent edge
    repeated_nodes=[]
    # Start adding the other n-m nodes. The first node is m.
    source=m
    d = {}
    while source<n:
        # Add edges to m nodes from the source.
        G.add_edges_from(zip([source]*m,targets))
        # Add one node to the list for each new edge just created.
        repeated_nodes.extend(targets)
        # And the new node "source" has m edges to add to the list.
        repeated_nodes.extend([source]*m)
        # Now choose m unique nodes from the existing nodes
        # Pick uniformly from repeated_nodes (preferential attachement)
        targets = _random_subset(repeated_nodes,m)
        deg = np.array(list(G.degree().values()))
        deg.sort()
        d[G.number_of_nodes()] = deg
        source += 1
    return G,d
```

let's try it:

```
g,d = barabasi_albert_graph_modified(10,2)
#out:
#{3: array([1, 1, 2]),
# 4: array([1, 2, 2, 3]),
# 5: array([1, 2, 2, 3, 4]),
# 6: array([1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 5]),
# 7: array([1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 6]),
# 8: array([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 7]),
# 9: array([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 5, 7]),
# 10: array([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8])}
```